# Sql Server Stored Procedure dynamically select table name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i have this stored procedure, I want to dynamically select table name based on the variable passing ie @Practice_Short_Name

```
 Create procedure [dbo].[GetCompleteCPTDetails]
    @Practice_Short_Name varchar(50) is Null,
    @Uploaded_Date varchar(30) is Null
 as
 begin
 DECLARE @CPTtablename varchar(100)
 DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(100)

 --Dynamically select Table name based on @practice_short_name
 set @CPTtablename ='ACER_CLAIMS_MASTER_DETAIL_Hist_'+@Practice_Short_Name+''

   SET @vQuery = 'select Practice_Short_Name,Service_Date_From,Carrier_Name,
   Location_Description,Patient_Number,Patient_First_Name,
   Patient_Last_Name,Voucher_Number,Procedure_Code,Service_Fees,
   Service_Payments,Service_Adjustments,Acer_Status,Acer_Allowed_Amount    

   from '+@CPTtablename+'

   where  Uploaded_Date ='+@Uploaded_Date+' and
   Practice_Short_Name ='+@Practice_Short_Name+'
   order by acer_status asc, Service_Date_From desc, Patient_First_Name asc'

EXEC @vQuery
end
GO
```

but while running this proc it is throwing error like

"Could not find stored procedure 'select Practice_Short_Name,Service_Date_From,Carrier_Name,
       Location_Description,Patient_Numb'."

can anyone explains me what i am doing wrong..

Comment: Have a look at [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). It will be safer to run than building dynamic sql with input parameters

Comment: Strange database design. Why a history table per practice short name instead of having one history table with a column for the practice short name, so you could use pure SQL to retrieve the data?

Comment: If i put all my data in one table then my application is running very slow. i have about 1800000+ records in a table.

Answer (score 2):

This way you call a procedure

```
EXEC @vQuery
```

but this way you run dynamic sql

```
EXEC (@vQuery)
```

so your SP should look as below

```
 Create procedure [dbo].[GetCompleteCPTDetails]
    @Practice_Short_Name varchar(50) is Null,
    @Uploaded_Date varchar(30) is Null
 as
 begin
 DECLARE @CPTtablename varchar(100)
 DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(100)

 --Dynamically select Table name based on @practice_short_name
 set @CPTtablename ='ACER_CLAIMS_MASTER_DETAIL_Hist_'+@Practice_Short_Name+''

   SET @vQuery = 'select Practice_Short_Name,Service_Date_From,Carrier_Name,
   Location_Description,Patient_Number,Patient_First_Name,
   Patient_Last_Name,Voucher_Number,Procedure_Code,Service_Fees,
   Service_Payments,Service_Adjustments,Acer_Status,Acer_Allowed_Amount    

   from '+@CPTtablename+'

   where  Uploaded_Date ='+@Uploaded_Date+' and
   Practice_Short_Name ='+@Practice_Short_Name+'
   order by acer_status asc, Service_Date_From desc, Patient_First_Name asc'

EXEC (@vQuery)
end
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable you use to store the query is too short to store the entire query text.
This means that the query is truncated to fix the 100 characters limit of the `@vQuery` variable.
Use `nvarchar(max)` instead of `nvarchar(100)`.

Also, using Dynamic SQL is usually a security hazard, leaving an opening to [SQL Injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/). You might want to re-think your design and keep all the data in the same table, instead of keeping different tables with the same structure on your datadase.

Comment: thankyou for your suggestion. But if i put all my data in one table my application is running very slow. in one table data is about 1800000+ rows. So i am separating data in different tables. if you can suggest me some other method it will be very appreciable.

Comment: depending on your specific conditions, you might be able to use 
[partitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787(v=sql.100).aspx) or perhaps just some simple [filtered indexes.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx), It's impossible to pinpoint the exact answerwithout knowing the exact nature of the data and demands.

Answer (score 0):

2 things need to be corrected : length of your dynamic query variable that caused you this problem. use parameterized dynamic query to prevent sql injection.

```
DECLARE @CPTtablename varchar(100)
DECLARE @vQuery NVARCHAR(2000) -- increased length, you can also use nvarchar(max)
--Dynamically select Table name based on @practice_short_name
SET @CPTtablename ='ACER_CLAIMS_MASTER_DETAIL_Hist_' + @Practice_Short_Name + ''
SET @vQuery = 'select Practice_Short_Name,Service_Date_From,Carrier_Name,
   Location_Description,Patient_Number,Patient_First_Name,
   Patient_Last_Name,Voucher_Number,Procedure_Code,Service_Fees,
   Service_Payments,Service_Adjustments,Acer_Status,Acer_Allowed_Amount    

   from ' + @CPTtablename + '

   where  Uploaded_Date = @Uploaded_Date and
   Practice_Short_Name = @Practice_Short_Name
   order by acer_status asc, Service_Date_From desc, Patient_First_Name asc'

--dynamic query with input params
EXEC sp_executesql
  @vQuery,
  N'@Uploaded_Date varchar(30), @Practice_Short_Name varchar(50)',
  @Uploaded_Date = @Uploaded_Date,
  @Practice_Short_Name = @Practice_Short_Name
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, as u suggested i increased the size of variable. but still it is not working fine. but if i remove where condition from my query then it will work fine. can u plz guide me in where condition what i am doing wrong.